# Energy Functional

Tags: general-relativity, energy, string-theory, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry

I am a graduate student in pure mathematics, during my study on [Ricci Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_flow) I faced some functional known as [energy functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_functional). For example Einstein-Hilbert functional is called an energy functional, also in Perelman's works $\mathcal{F}(g,f)=\int_M(R+|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f}d\mu$ is introduced as an energy functuional, where $M$ is a closed manifold, $g$ is Riemannian metric, $R$ is Ricci scalar, and $f$ is any function that in the physics literature is called [dilaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilaton).

I do not know why these functionals are attributed to the energy concept and why does $f$ show dilaton concept?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/369098/11127

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $f$ is just an arbitrary scalar function on the manifold. I'm not well-versed with the concept of Ricci flow, so I'll try to give a simple operational answer. I also don't understand what exactly you're looking for.

The Ricci scalar $R$ roughly represents the amount of energy stored in spacetime (as curvature). The dilaton is a scalar field which sets the length scale (how much "dilation") at at each point.

The dilaton $\phi$ typically acts on the metric as $e^{-2\phi}$ which is why you see $e^{-f}$ in your energy functional.